# Определение языка клавиатуры в Android

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу приложение и нужно определить либо язык уже в введённого текста (ru|en) либо как-то определять язык клавиатуры, с которой пользователь вводит текст в строку. Кто-либо знает, как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В андроиде можно определить локаль, по ней сделать вывод о языке
2. Более надежный способ - взять введеный текст и например проверить первую букву слова со словарем, если она есть в русском - значит русский, если в английском...
3. Может как то можно на грузить гугл для авто определения слов языка )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395478/best-java-library-for-automatic-language-identification

Тут предлагается спец либа для этого

http://habrahabr.ru/post/52239/

Тут альтернатива

Comment: 1.Локаль это определение локации,а мне нужно именно клавиатуры или самого текста язык узнать.
2.А что за словарь?
3.Вот может и да.. но как..

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier локаль не имеет отношения к локации. Локаль это [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то это довольно сложно по введенному тексту найти к какому `charset`'у принадлежит текст. [Гугль наводит](https://www.google.com/#java+charset+detector) на несколько источников/способов

Comment: По ссылке не переходит, может потому что с планшета..

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier поищите ключевые слова *java charset detector*